# Why does this PL-SQL loop only work when executing it separately from DDL statements?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

#### Problem

I am trying to perform some DDL statements to create a temporary table, then execute a loop over a cursor in PL/SQL to copy some data into the newly created temporary table, and then do some more DDL to do some final adjustments to the table after the data got copied over.

However, I end up with the error message

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" is not declared
```

and nothing after the initial DDL (i.e. nothing from the loop or after it) gets executed.

Strangely enough, if I execute the statements one after another (first the DDL, then the loop, then the remaining DDL) instead of a single batch with SQL Developer, it works like a charm. That might be a last resort if everything else fails, but the preferred solution would be to do everything at once, so we can just hand out a single update script for people to use. And I am wondering what the issue is in the first place.

#### Motivation

I need to modify some columns in a table that contains a large amount of data (several million rows and perhaps 30 columns). Altering the columns directly would cause the transactions to become too large, so I opted to do the following instead:

1. Create a table with the new column definitions.
2. Copy the data over while performing a commit every couple thousand entries.
3. Drop all constraints and indices referencing the old table.
4. Drop the old table.
5. Rename the new table to the old one.
6. Recreate the constraints and indices on the new table.

#### Minimal reproducible sample

The following minimal sample illustrates the steps mentioned above, though I left out any indices and foreign keys for brevity.

First the definition of the table that should be migrated.

```
-- This is the old table A.
CREATE TABLE TestA (
  ID number not null,
  Val varchar2(20 CHAR),
  constraint PK_TestA primary key 
  (
    ID
  )
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TestA
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TRIGGER TRI_TestA
BEFORE INSERT ON TestA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  SELECT SEQ_TestA.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
.
RUN;

-- Insert some test data.
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Hello');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('World');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Foo');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Bar');

commit;
```

Then is the actual migration script:

```
-- Create the new table B with the new column definitions.
CREATE TABLE TestB (
  ID number not null,
  Val nvarchar2(50),
  constraint PK_TestB primary key 
  (
    ID
  )
);

-- Copy data from A to B and commit every once in a while.
DECLARE
  counter number := 0;
  CURSOR migrationrows
  IS
    SELECT
      ID,
      Val
    FROM TestA;

BEGIN
  FOR migrationrow
  IN migrationrows
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO TestB (
      ID,
      Val
    )
    VALUES
    (
      migrationrow.ID,
      migrationrow.Val
    );

    counter := counter + 1;
    IF counter > 2 THEN
      commit;
      counter := 0;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;

-- Now get rid of the old A and make B the new A.
DROP TRIGGER TRI_TestA;

DROP TABLE TestA;

ALTER TABLE TestB RENAME TO TestA;
ALTER TABLE TestA RENAME CONSTRAINT PK_TestB TO PK_TestA;

CREATE TRIGGER TRI_TestA
BEFORE INSERT ON TestA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  SELECT SEQ_TestA.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
.
RUN;

commit;
```

If I run this from each step where I placed the comment lines, it works. But if I run it altogether, I get the error shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely because you're missing the `/`s from the end of your pl/sql and trigger statements.

E.g. your scripts should look something like:

```
-- This is the old table A.
CREATE TABLE TestA (
  ID number not null,
  Val varchar2(20 CHAR),
  constraint PK_TestA primary key 
  (
    ID
  )
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TestA
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TRIGGER TRI_TestA
BEFORE INSERT ON TestA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  SELECT SEQ_TestA.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/

-- Insert some test data.
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Hello');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('World');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Foo');
INSERT INTO TestA (Val) VALUES ('Bar');

commit;
```

and

```
-- Create the new table B with the new column definitions.
CREATE TABLE TestB (
  ID number not null,
  Val nvarchar2(50),
  constraint PK_TestB primary key 
  (
    ID
  )
);

-- Copy data from A to B and commit every once in a while.
DECLARE
  counter number := 0;
  CURSOR migrationrows
  IS
    SELECT
      ID,
      Val
    FROM TestA;

BEGIN
  FOR migrationrow
  IN migrationrows
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO TestB (
      ID,
      Val
    )
    VALUES
    (
      migrationrow.ID,
      migrationrow.Val
    );

    counter := counter + 1;
    IF counter > 2 THEN
      commit;
      counter := 0;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
/

-- Now get rid of the old A and make B the new A.
DROP TRIGGER TRI_TestA;

DROP TABLE TestA;

ALTER TABLE TestB RENAME TO TestA;
ALTER TABLE TestA RENAME CONSTRAINT PK_TestB TO PK_TestA;

CREATE TRIGGER TRI_TestA
BEFORE INSERT ON TestA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  SELECT SEQ_TestA.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

Also, you don't need to select your next sequence value in a select statement, you can simply do:

```
:new.id := SEQ_TestA.NEXTVAL;
```

And why are you fetching across a commit? You could just do a straight:

```
insert into testb (id,
                   val)
select id,
       val
from   testa;
```

You can store the number of rows inserted by storing `SQL%ROWCOUNT` in a variable immediately after running the insert statement.

Comment: Oh my god, yes, this was the issue. I've been at this for two consecutive days now. D:

Comment: Concerning the "fetch across a commit": I am pretty novice in Oracle, but in SQL-Server we basically solved the same issue (transaction log file size grows too large during DDL changes to tables with large amount of data) by doing intermediate commits. So the train of thought was to apply the same principle to Oracle and make intermediate commits. Using the `INSERT INTO () SELECT` would just do everything in one big transaction, wouldn't it? Wouldn't that cause issues with the redo log size as well? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your main problem with redo logs is running out of disk space. I would hope, if you're migrating data, that your disk space would be adequately sized! You could always create the table in nologging mode and then do a direct-path insert (don't forget to switch the table back to logging mode, though!) if you're really concerned about redo log space. Your current way of committing after every single row is the slowest way you could migrate this data (apart from things like manually keying it yourself, etc!).

Comment: The single row is just for the example purpose. In reality it would be more like every 1000th or 10000th row. But I'll take it into consideration, thanks.

Comment: It's still going to be slower than the insert-as-select. And you run the possibility of running into the `ORA-01555: snapshot too old` error.